# I have a graphql query. How can I manage my 'title' useState with it? I'd like that the title would be in the query instead of "Bad boys" to send

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a graphql query and a working useState.
How can I manage my 'title' useState with it? I'd like that the title would be in the query instead of "Bad boys" to send.

```
    function Home() {
  const [title, setTitle] = useState("");

  const searchMovies = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("submitting");

    const query = `{
    searchMovies(query: "Bad boys") {
    id
    name
    overview
    releaseDate
    cast {
      id
      person {
        name
      }
      role {
        ... on Cast {
          character
        }
      }
    }
  }
}`;


    const url = "https://tmdb.sandbox.zoosh.ie/dev/graphql";

    try {
      request("https://tmdb.sandbox.zoosh.ie/dev/graphql", query).then((data) =>
        console.log(data)
      );
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

The query is an interpolated string so you can pass variables into it like this:

```
const query = `{
    searchMovies(query: ${title}) {
    id
    name
    overview
    releaseDate
    cast {
      id
      person {
        name
      }
      role {
        ... on Cast {
          character
        }
      }
    }
  }
}`;
```